# Compare two arrays from two different dataframes in Pyspark

Tags: arrays, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes ecah has an array(string) columns.

I am trying to create a new data frame that only filters rows where one of the array element in a row matches with other.

```
#first dataframe
main_df = spark.createDataFrame([('1', ['YYY', 'MZA']),
    ('2', ['XXX','YYY']),
    ('3',['QQQ']),
     ('4', ['RRR', 'ZZZ', 'BBB1'])],
    ('No', 'refer_array_col'))

#second dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1A',    '3412asd','value-1',    ['XXX', 'YYY', 'AAA']),
('2B',  '2345tyu','value-2',    ['DDD', 'YFFFYY', 'GGG', '1']),
('3C',  '9800bvd',  'value-3',  ['AAA']),
 ('3C', '9800bvd',  'value-1',  ['AAA', 'YYY', 'CCCC'])],
('ID',  'Company_Id',   'value' ,'array_column'))

df.show()

+---+----------+-------+--------------------+
| ID|Company_Id|  value|      array_column  |
+---+----------+-------+--------------------+
| 1A|   3412asd|value-1|   [XXX, YYY, AAA]  |
| 2B|   2345tyu|value-2|[DDD, YFFFYY, GGG, 1]|
| 3C|   9800bvd|value-3|             [AAA]   |
| 3C|   9800bvd|value-1|  [AAA, YYY, CCCC]   |
+---+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

**Code I tried:**

*The main idea is to use **rdd.toLocalIterator()** as there are some other functions inside the same for loop that are depending on this filters*

```
for x in main_df.rdd.toLocalIterator:
    a = main_df["refer_array_col"]
     b = main_df["No"]
     some_x_filter = F.col('array_coulmn').isin(b)  
   

    final_df = df.filter(
       # filter 1
       some_x_filter &           
       # second filter is to compare 'a' with array_column - i tried using F.array_contains
       (F.array_contains(F.col('array_column'), F.lit(a)))     
)
```

- some_x_filter is also working in a similar way
- some_x_filter is comparing a string value in a array of strings column.
- But now `a` contains a list of strings and I am unable to compare it with array_column

With my code I am getting an error for array contains

**Error**

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList ['YYY', 'MZA']
```

Can anyone tell me what can i use at the second filter alternatively?

Comment: Could you add your expected output?

Comment: I actually do not understand what `rdd.toLocalIterator: ` is doing in the for loop. I think `a` is getting compared to all the rows in `df` and filtering out the `True` values.  please correct me if i am wrong. @Emma

Comment: I guess you want a join operation: `result = main_df.join(df, F.arrays_overlap(main_df["refer_array_col"], df["array_column"]))`

Comment: @blackbishop - Actually I want to add a filter same as the other filter (refer some_x_filter exmple)

Comment: @Bella_18 sure, you can add it in the join condition `F.arrays_overlap(main_df["refer_array_col"], df["array_column"]) & some_x_filter`

Comment: Can i use `F.arrays_overlap(F.col("array_column"), main_df["refer_array_col"]) & some_x_filter` instead?

Comment: I do not want to change the structure of code as many other filters depend on that @blackbishop -- I am getting this error if i use F.col - `There is an error in the column reference ['YYY', 'MZA']. Common errors include not referencing a list of columns using *[] or not explicitly using column literals. Please review your code.`

Comment: `rdd.toLocalIterator` will iterate over rows, however, you do not want to iterate in Pyspark. Instead you want to write "instructions" how Spark should translate a column. That way Spark will distribute the computation and optimize it. Could you show what is `some_x_filter` and what is your expected output, we might able to come up with an alternative approach that doesn't involve `toLocalIterator`.

Comment: @Emma I have added what `some_x_filter` is doing in the question. a string value is getting compared to array of string column. Now similarly i want to compare list with array of strings column.

Comment: @Emma I have added more description now. can you please check and tell me if it is clear

Comment: @Bella_18 Do you want to filter rows in one dataframe if they have a value contained in array from another dataframe? If yes I can help you. Just today answered a similar problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75028546/joining-pyspark-dataframes-on-exact-match-of-a-whole-word-in-a-string-pyspark/75030722#75030722

Comment: Or are you looking - if there are any common elements in those arrays then filter out that row?

Comment: Yes. If any one element matches then array_contains will return true @RonakJain

Comment: `a` has a list now, as I used `rdd.tolociterator()` I have to filter the rows that contain any one element of the list `a` @RonakJain. Is it possible for you to give the answer by editing the code that I gave? I mean to add inside `df.filter`

Comment: @Bella_18 I'm not sure what  rdd.tolociterator() is for here, but I can provide you way to achieve the end goal -> Row with column value within a list from another dataframe should "retain", right?

Comment: @Bella_18 Where is your iterator value 'x' being used? I don't think the loop is required

Comment: @RonakJain if any one element from the list `a` matches with any one element of row. then it should retain. the filter is exactly same to `some_x_filter`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250906/discussion-between-ronak-jain-and-bella-18).

Comment: Once I am inside the for loop- in the first iteration `a` contains `['YYY', 'MZA']` -- so now this a is checked inside the `df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood based on our conversation in the comments.

Essentially your requirement is to compare an array column with a Python List.

Thus, this would do the job

```
df.withColumn("asArray", F.array(*[F.lit(x) for x in b]))
```

Comment: Hey, I have a doubt. when comparing a python list with None, the function would return None right? How can I avoid this @Ronak Jain

Comment: Also, if both elements to be compared are None - array_overlap is returning True

Comment: Answer you gave: `F.arrays_overlap(F.col("array_column"),F.col("asArray"))` which would usually return either True or False. How can I make this null proof?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250906/discussion-between-ronak-jain-and-bella-18

Comment: I tried but could not find a solution. Did you find an alternative?

Comment: @Bella_18 Hi, I haven't checked yet as I am away currently, will do once I am in position and update the same in the chat room.

Comment: @Bella_18 Hi, can you check one update and respond.